# Why does Visual Studio tell me that a database exists when it does not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I get the following error, but I am certain the database does not exist.  Why does Visual Studio tell me that it does ?  Maybe it did exist at one time, but I have searched the entire hard drive and it is no where to be found.

```
 [SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'C:\Users\develop1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ToolingDevelopmentFolder3\ColdDrawWeb2\App_Data\aspnet-ColdDrawWeb3-20131218105113.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
```

Comment: You made sure its not in `App_Data` directory of your project

Comment: Yes I did.  It's not there.

Comment: perhaps you should clean the project? I would also run the DROP database query manually from server explorer see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for that mdf file. Look for another mdf file with a completely different name, but that represents a database with the same name in Sql Server.